# Get different color from a pool of colors

Tags: javascript

I have an array of colors

```
const chartCanvas = [
  '#FF3F0B',
  '#FF8202',
  '#FF0232',
  '#24FFBA',
  '#A61BE3',
  '#FFABBC',
  '#FFF49B',
  '#006BD6',
  '#76DB00',
];
```

Except for that I have an array of objects which a user has select.

```
const selectedObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: ...
  }
  ....
 
]
```

What I want to do is every time a user selects a new object, I want to assing an unused color from the colors array into the selected object. If the objects are more than the available colors, I want to give the first color again, etc etc.

I need to mention that the user can un-select an object too, so it is not possible to give colors according to the index of the object.

I can use a double forEach but I dont think its very efficient.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

What I have do right now is

```
const color = chartCanvas[(selectedObjects.length ) % chartCanvas.length];

const tempData: Channel_Chart_Data = {
      date: ['17 oct', '18 oct', '19 oct', '20 oct', '21 oct', '22 oct', '23 oct'],
      views: [232, 245, 267, 300, 450, 700, 1250],
      id: channel_id,
      label: 'What a nice label',
      color: color,
    };
selectedObjects = [...selectedObjects, tempData]
```

But it doesnt work since user can uncheck an object...

Comment: can you add your working code? and how you use `selectedObjects`

Comment: @appleapple i did, thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a counter which you increment when the user selects an object, that can then be used as an index to access an element of the array of colours. To ensure that you always are accessing a valid index of the array, clamp the index to the length of the array by using the modulus operator.

```js
const chartCanvas = [
  '#FF3F0B',
  '#FF8202',
  '#FF0232',
  '#24FFBA',
  '#A61BE3',
  '#FFABBC',
  '#FFF49B',
  '#006BD6',
  '#76DB00',
];

const selectedObjects = [];

const contentElem = document.querySelector('#selected-objects');

let id = 0;

let colorIdx = 0;

window.clicked = function() {
  selectedObjects.push({ 
    id,
    color: chartCanvas[colorIdx]
  });
  
  id = id + 1;
  
  colorIdx = (colorIdx + 1) % chartCanvas.length; // <- important bit
  
  contentElem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selectedObjects, null, 2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clicked()">Click me</button>
<div id="selected-objects"></div>
```

Alternatively, if `id` is a number starting from zero, you could use that to select the color, along with the modulus trick demoed above:

```js
const chartCanvas = [
  '#FF3F0B',
  '#FF8202',
  '#FF0232',
  '#24FFBA',
  '#A61BE3',
  '#FFABBC',
  '#FFF49B',
  '#006BD6',
  '#76DB00',
];

const selectedObjects = [];

const contentElem = document.querySelector('#selected-objects');

let id = 0;

window.clicked = function() {
  selectedObjects.push({ 
    id,
    color: chartCanvas[id % chartCanvas.length] // <- important bit
  });
  
  id = id + 1;
  
  contentElem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selectedObjects, null, 2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clicked()">Click me</button>
<div id="selected-objects"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. build a reference array containing your colors.
2. create a copy of the reference array that will be your pool of colors
3. when a user select an object you pop a color from your array.

- If the user unselect an object you can add the now unused color back into the array.
- If you pool is empty you can copy the reference array again.